# Proving convexity of a function whose Hessian is positive semidefinite over a convex set

Tags: derivatives, optimization, continuity, convex-optimization

Let $C$ be a convex set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $f:{\mathbb{R}}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be twice continuously differentiable over $C$.

The Hessian of $f$ is positive semidefinite over $C$, and I want to show that $f$ is therefore a convex function.

I am currently trying to apply Taylor's Theorem to replace $f(x)$ with an expression that includes its Hessian.

Comment: Well, I suppose I haven't "tried" a proof. I'm trying to figure out what information I can gain about f or the domain of f simply based on the Hessian's values over a convex set. I'm pretty much stuck at the gates.

Comment: Can you prove it's true in 1 dimension? Because if you restrict the function to a line it reduces to that case.

Comment: @p.s.Thank you very much for your comment. I was able to prove it's true in 1 dimension, but I'm having difficulty understanding what you mean by "restrict[ing] the function to a line" and how I would communicate that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm assuming what you would like to show is that if $f$ has positive semidefinite Hessian, then for all $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}$ in the domain, and $t \in [0,1]$, we have:
$$
f(t \mathbf{x} + (1-t) \mathbf{y}) \le t f(\mathbf{x})  + (1-t) f(\mathbf{y})
$$
To reduce it to the one-dimensional case, fix $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ and look at the function restricted to the line segment connecting those points. That is, define the one-dimensional function:
$$g(t) = f(t \mathbf{x} + (1-t) \mathbf{y})$$
Then we can compute the derivatives of $g$:
$$g'(t) = ( \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y})^T \mathbf{\nabla}f(t \mathbf{x} + (1-t) \mathbf{y})$$
$$g''(t) = ( \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y})^T \mathbf{\nabla^2}f(t \mathbf{x} + (1-t) \mathbf{y}) ( \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y})$$
Since the Hessian is positive semidefinite, we have $g''(t) \ge 0$ for all $t$. Then we use this with Taylor's theorem to prove that:
$$
\begin{aligned}
g(0) &\ge g(t) + g'(t)(-t)\\
g(1) &\ge g(t) + g'(t)(1-t)
\end{aligned}
$$
Then if $t \in [0,1]$, these can then be combined to give:
$$
g(t) \le tg(1) + (1-t)g(0)
$$
which is equivalent to the inequality we wanted to prove.

Comment: I'm really struggling to prove that if g''(t) >= 0 then that inequality holds. Can I (or "would you") use Taylor's theorem to make that leap?

Comment: The reason I asked if you knew how to do the 1-d case is that I had actually forgotten how to do it. =) But it's explained in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513887/second-derivative-positive-implies-convex). I expanded my answer a little.

Comment: How come when computing $g'(t)$, we get an $(x-y)^T$ but when we compute a second derivative $g''(t)$, we get an $(x-y)$ instead of another $(x-y)^T$?

Comment: If it helps, $\nabla f$ is the gradient, a vector. $\nabla^2 f$ is the Hessian, a matrix. Whereas $g$ and its derivatives are scalars. You could also write $g'(t)=\nabla f(..)^T (x-y)$ since for column vectors $u^Tv=v^Tu$.

Comment: The third and the second from the last equations should have used a new variable $c \in (a, b)$, rather than messing up with $t$ which has other meaning in previous context. It's really a bad habit to reuse letters (especially without claiming) in the same proof.

Comment: Obviously the proof is wrong since the condition for  both g(0)> g(t)+g'(t)(-t) and g(1)>= g(t)+g'(t)(1-t) to be correct is not satisified, one requires that t be close enough to 0 and the other requires that t be close enough to 1.

Comment: Hello @p.s. !! Could you give also the structure of the proof for the other direction? We consider that $f$ is convex, that means that $f(tx+(1-t)y)\leq tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)$.

We want to show that the Hessian matrix is positive semidefinite, i.e.that $\mathbf z^T H \mathbf z \ge 0$, for each $z$.

For that do we assume that it is not true, i.e. that there is one $z$ that this inequality doesn't hold and we get a contradiction?

Comment: You need some more conditions than just convexity to prove the reverse - I think existence and continuity of the Hessian will do it. So, if the Hessian has a negative eigenvector at a point then you can use a similar argument to show that in along the direction of the eigenvector the function must be strictly concave in a neighboorhood, which would contradict convexity. Again you need to use continuity, so I'm not sure which form of Taylor's theorem would work though.